After render done, render output is not showing in folder
I am new to Blender and I am facing weird issue. When I press f12 to render my png output single frame. my output is not showing in location. kindly help me with this

f12 does not save your render, it just renders it into memory. If you wanna save your render, go to "image"-> save after rendering (in the rendering window).

Hi, I am sorry can u explain me steps in more detail..or share a link related to this issue? I am totally new to Blender. Thank you for ur time

just hit F12...then a window should popup. There is a menu. Click on Image -> save.

It's worked :). Thank You Chris!!

Just to add to Chris' information, if you closed the render window you can bring it back with F11 to show the render result (no need to render again), then you can save the image. Another info: the output path which you can specify is for rendering animations (Ctrl+F12), because when you are rendering a sequence instead of a single frame the images are saved automatically because otherwise each new render would overwrite the previous in memory. By the way, by setting Start and End to the same number you can render a single frame as animation and it will be saved automatically.
